# How to keep seaborn xtick labels the same for each plot iteration?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have payment data for three customers with the Month&Year of each payment:

```
              user_id  amount  Mon_Year
2076273          1664  245.16  Jan-2019
3682561          1664  122.58  Jul-2019
5437947          1664  109.43  Nov-2019
6067277          1664  218.86  Dec-2019
1911317          3396  319.00  Jan-2019
6079810          3396  360.00  Dec-2019
1961388          4192  104.28  Jan-2019
2500575          4192  104.28  Mar-2019
2709024          4192  104.28  Apr-2019
3049894          4192  104.28  May-2019
```

And I can create a plot for each customer fine:

```
for user in df.user_id.unique():
    temp = df[df['user_id']==user]
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
    ax = sns.barplot(x="Mon_Year", y="amount", data=temp,ci=None)
    ax.set_title(f'transactions for user: {user}')
    ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=30)
    plt.show()
```

[image: plots]

However I would like each plot to have the same xticks (all the dates in `Mon_Year` column) so plots have the same scale.

Plot # 2 is missing some months, so ideally it will have empty bars. I will be able to compare customers a bit easier, and see which months nothing was spent. Like this:

[image]

I tried to use `xlim` but completely broke it, I think this only works for numerical data, but `Mon_Year` is categorical.

For this sample df, the range of xticks goes from Jan 2019 to Dec 2019:

```
df.Mon_Year.unique()

array(['Jan-2019', 'Jul-2019', 'Nov-2019', 'Dec-2019', 'Mar-2019',
       'Apr-2019', 'May-2019'], dtype=object)
```

Notice that in the df, I have them all pre-sorted in Monthly order for each customer.

How can I set `xlim` with categorical data and keep it the same for each iteration of the plots?

Mu sample df:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'index': pd.Series([2076273, 3682561, 5437947, 6067277, 1911317, 6079810, 1961388, 2500575, 2709024, 3049894],dtype='int64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1)), 'user_id': pd.Series(['1664', '1664', '1664', '1664', '3396', '3396', '4192', '4192', '4192', '4192'],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1)), 'amount': pd.Series([245.16, 122.58, 109.43, 218.86, 319.0, 360.0, 104.28, 104.28, 104.28, 104.28],dtype='float64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1)), 'Mon_Year': pd.Series(['Jan-2019', 'Jul-2019', 'Nov-2019', 'Dec-2019', 'Jan-2019', 'Dec-2019', 'Jan-2019', 'Mar-2019', 'Apr-2019', 'May-2019'],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1))}, index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10, step=1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your loop to add all month-year values into the `temp` dataframe. This will add NaN values for `index` and `amount` in the new rows and an empty space in the resulting plot.

```
mon_year = ['Jan-2019', 'Feb-2019', 'Mar-2019', 'Apr-2019', 'May-2019', 'Jun-2019', 'Jul-2019','Aug-2019', 'Sept-2019', 'Oct-2019', 'Nov-2019', 'Dec-2019']

for user in df.user_id.unique():
    temp = df[df['user_id']==user].set_index('Mon_Year')
    temp = temp.reindex(mon_year)
    temp = temp.reset_index()
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
    ax = sns.barplot(x="Mon_Year", y="amount", data=temp,ci=None)
    ax.set_title(f'transactions for user: {user}')
    ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=30)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and report back :)

Comment: Ok, It's working for most of my users. Some have more than one payment in a `Mon_Year" period which causes a problem. I need to fix that. Otherwise it works, thanks.